# To invoke code before loading eclipse splash screen

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I have created a eclipse product using product configuration (.product) file. I want to display a dialog before the eclipse splash screen(the product screen) appears for some validation.Since am launching the product from the configuration(.product) file,i dont have an IApplication implementation to do the same.

Usage of startup extension is not useful as the control is given to startup extension only after loading the workbench.How this usecase can be supported ? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Santhosh

Answer (score 0):

The startup extension is the earliest place you could get control because, for performance reasons, your plugin won't be started until the user explicitly requests some action that requires your plugin.  If you have to run some validation earlier, your two choices are to modify the base Eclipse code and deliver a modified Eclipse platform with your product or perform the validation when you install your plugin.

For completeness, I'll also note that some repackagers of the Eclipse platform (IBM Rational comes to mind.  Others have done this, too) have at times included a licensing component that you might be able to plug in to.

Answer (score 0):

[This blog](http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2007/06/12/splash-screen-and-threads/) describes how to add a login-dialog as part of the splash-screen. Is this what you want to accomplish?